# Display Flex, I need to put an icon behind the text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

## Display Flex bug

> **I'm trying to make this icon just in front of the text** but there must be flex and aligin-contet: center; otherwise the text would be such a scatter you will see in the photo where there is a red line so I have already used `display:flex; and aligin-content: center;` I need to do it somehow so that the icon is still and the show somehow I can't do it I've been doing it for 2 days and they've never helped me yet.

```css
#autocomplete a {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #111;
        padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
        border-radius: 20px;
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
    }
    
#autocomplete .fa.fa-search {
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

without Flex and `content-aligin: center;`
[image: without Flex and content-aligin: center;]

with Flex and `content-aligin: center;`
[image: with Flex and content-aligin: center;]

Comment: post relevant code

Comment: @Jason Oh sorry, i am added the code now.

Comment: I have thoroughly compared your two pictures, they seem absolutely identic to me. Additionally, as @Jason asked for, please supply some code in order for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ahuemmer Sorry i upload miss photo wait i go fix it

Comment: @ahuemmer Really, Thanks for your Answer but is for my website not working, can you Look on my website if i give you url the your code is not bad but i have problems with the your code to add to my code can you look on my website if i give you url? i have problem with  

#autocomplete a *  but i cant use the code becuse i need redirect <a> href but if i delte <a> and add <span> is stop works.

Comment: @Whatery1010, OK, I've tried with your site heexy.org you mentioned. It seemed to work for me. What did you mean with "delete `<a>`"? I meant, you should not delete anything, just add the CSS style and the new `<span>`.

Comment: @ahuemmer Can you send me the code what you edit? whats you add on the Website? is working?

Comment: @Whatery1010, I've inline-edited your code with browser tools, so I can't send you anything more. You need to add the `#autocomplete a *` block to your CSS file (probably `autocomplete.css`) and make the logic wrap the bold content into a span. The latter one is the trickier one, I assume, you would have to do this in your `index.js`, but I can't really figure it out because the code on your site was kind of minimized.

Comment: @ahuemmer Oh, Thank you, try use flex-direction: row-reverse; is working on 50% is change the side on right but is works i only must change the side right to left. this is answer by Ori Guy https://imgur.com/a/PjNpGCN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using "flex-direction: row-reverse;" it should reverse your items inside the container with the display flex applied.

have a nice day and good luck

Comment: Really Thank you but Is working on 50% Is change the postiiton on right side look https://imgur.com/a/PjNpGCN

Comment: You have very good Idea with **flex-direction: row-reverse;** but only one problem is here we are must change the side Right to left do you have idea how make it?

Comment: I think you put the display flex on the parent container.
you need to do the reverse on the  container that wraps the two elements.
also, you can try to style it with the position left,right not float.
the try to change the align-items: center; to flex-start

Comment: I use and is now working but Really thank you for help me
justify-content: flex-end;
flex-direction: row-reverse;

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be like this:

1. Add the following CSS definition:

```css
#autocomplete a * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

2. The "bold" text is outside a `span` or similar element. You should also put it into a `<span>`, so the correct style will be applied to it.

Example:

```html
<a href="./search?q=abcdef&amp;source=autocomplete" data-index="1">
   <span class="nobold">abc</span>
   <span>def</span>
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</a>
```

(The `span` around `def` is the new one.)

**Explanation:**

The `*` in the CSS definition in 1. will make the style apply to the selected element *and all its children*. So, in 2. you just add a matching "child" by using the `span`. I've tested it and it works for me.

Hint: I don't know if you know about this technique, but you can always use the browser's development tools in order to try such things "on the fly" within the page being shown.

Comment: Really, Thanks for your Answer but is for my website not working, can you Look on my website if i give you url the your code is not bad but i have problems with the your code to add to my code can you look on my website if i give you url? i have problem with #autocomplete a * but i cant use the code becuse i need redirect <a> href but if i delte <a> and add <span> is stop works.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i am working on this and the Ori Guy add me some Idea and i make this code

```
justify-content: flex-end;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

And look is working :D

[image: YEY!]

Really Thank all who help ME!! THANK YOU <3